# How do I add CSS styles to an ASP.NET UserControl from the code-behind?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, css

```
this.Style.Add ( /*...*/ )
```

... doesn't appear to work.

What do I need to do to add a style to it?

Comment: Does your control inherit from existing Web control?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: No, it does not. It inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about the nature of UserControl - it's intended to contain other ASP.NET controls and that's why you cannot set CSS for whole control.. instead you just need to specify styles for each child control individually. You can also take a look at the [ApplyStyleSheetSkin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.applystylesheetskin.aspx) method.

Comment: doesn't make sense. I want to load specific styles in my page when there is at least one instance of my user control. That sould be done with something similar to RegisterStartupScripts (for javascript) but for css styles instead

Answer (score 2):

You may wrap your user control into another html container (div for example) and set style on container.

Answer (score 1):

If your user control is inheriting from webcontrol simply use the [system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass (msdn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx).  Example in the link.